# backspace equivalent delimiter in javascript like '\n' for new line

Tags: javascript, delimiter, backspace

what is the backspace equivalent in javscript like '\n' is for new line.

purpose-
i want to re write the URL with our redirecting the page. presently i am using
`window.history.pushState(null,'title','/something');`

example-
this only replaces this **https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=TKFZUrGxOIeOrQfG34DICw** with **https://www.google.co.in/something**

so i indent to flush the entire url and re-write the domain name also.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special character in JavaScript that would delete previous characters in a string.

For security reasons you can't add a page to the browser history that has a different domain than the page that's manipulating the history, or change the URL to show a different domain. You can't go around this restriction.